# Как правильно создавать запросы с неопределенным количеством параметров?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Допустим есть некое приложение, работающее с MSSQL-базой.
Параметры фильтрации записей должен определять пользователь. Заранее неизвестно, какие фильтры он задаст или нет.
В данный момент я запрограммировал это путем конкатенации строк в зависимости от значений контролов на форме.
Но хотелось бы узнать, как это делается правильно?

```
string loadcmd = "select distinct check_id, name as 'Название документа', sum as Сумма, username as Добавлен, checks.user_id from dbo.checks, dbo.users where dbo.checks.user_id=dbo.users.user_id";

    if (dateTC1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        loadcmd = loadcmd + " and date>='" + chDateFrom.Value + "' and date<='" + chDateTill.Value + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        if (dateTC1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            loadcmd = loadcmd + " and month(date)='" + dtpChecks.Value.Month + "' and year(date)='" + dtpChecks.Value.Year + "'";
        }
    }


    if (userCbox.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        loadcmd = loadcmd + "  and (dbo.checks.user_id=7 or checks.user_id = '" + userCbox.SelectedValue + "')";
    }

    if (filter_shop_id != 0)
    {
        loadcmd = loadcmd + " and checks.shop = '"+filter_shop_id+"'";
    }
```

Comment: не идеальное решение, но я бы упаковал поисковый запрос в хранимку с нужным числом опциональных параметров и там уже в зависимости от значений переданных параметров добавлял условия в запрос через SQL-конструкцию CASE например

Comment: То есть создать кейс на каждый случай? Нет конечно в моем случае, их будет не больше 10-15. Но хочется знать best practice.

Comment: ну кейсами можно добавлять или игнорировать условия в where, так что технически запрос будет один, а блок where будет меняться в зависимости от наличия параметров, т.е. значение не null. Как вариант использовать dynamic sql, но это на мой вкус не очень здорово

Comment: Именно вот в таких случаях - динамическое составление запроса в зависимости от условий - невероятно рулят ORM наподобие EF и linq2db. Рассмотрите возможность их использования в вашем проекте.

Comment: [Хрестоматийное](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: Спасибо, i-one. Помогло.